# SCSS function to change opacity of rgba or hex color

Tags: css, sass, colors

I am injecting CSS variables into `.scss` and in some cases I want that I reduce the opacity. The colours can be HEX or RGBA (depending of user selection).

I have tried some of the scss methods but it does not work.

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: rgba(var(--primary), 0.5) !important;
}
```

This results in only white.

Also:

```
.bg-primary {
  background-color: transparentize(var(--primary), 0.5) !important;
}
```

But it gives me error:

```
SassError: var(--primaryBootstrapColor) is not a color.
node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[1]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/common/styles/
```

Packages:

```
 "sass": "^1.49.9",
 "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
 "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
```

Comment: SASS knows nothing about CSS custom properties (variables). SASS is a **pre**processor; it runs before the CSS is processed, so `var(--primaryBootstrapColor)` is meaningless.

Comment: How about CSS? Is such a thing possible with plain css. I tried in css file also rgba() but no success.